# Displaying a photo for an Application endpoint

Tags: lync, ucma

Here is my problem :
I work on a big UCMA project since 3 month and now I would like to add a little feature.

I have a lot of ApplicationEndpoints which can be added, modified or deleted dynamically and I would like, each time that I create an ApplicationEndpoint, to specify a picture which will be displayed on Microsoft Lync.

I already have a lot of other functionnalities but I'd really like to have this one.

I searched for days but I didn't find anything so before telling myself that it can't be done, I wanted to ask !

Does anyone know if that is possible ? In that case, could you show me the way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, but this might help someone.

I'm not sure if this is possible for an application endpoint, but you can publish photo settings for a user endpoint for sure (I have done this and it works). Some basic info on publishing presence can be found on MSDN: [Publishing Presence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/dd253494%28v=office.13%29.aspx).

Publishing presence information (which includes photo settings) is done on the `LocalEndpoint.LocalOwnerPresence`. Both `UserEndpoint` and `ApplicationEndpoint` derive from `LocalEndpoint`, so this should be doable really.

The actual publishing gets slightly complex because there are a lot of different combinations of 'levels' to publish on:

First, there are a bunch of `InstanceID` values that you need to know about, read up on them here: [Presence data source and category instance ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh380066.aspx)

Second, there is a value for who this presence applies to, see `Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Presence.PresenceRelationshipLevel`. Don't publish on `Unknown`, you'll get an exception.

```
public enum PresenceRelationshipLevel  
{  
    Unknown = -1,  
    Everyone = 0,  
    External = 100,  
    Colleagues = 200,  
    Workgroup = 300,  
    Personal = 400,  
    Blocked = 32000,  
}
```

You need to publish a `PresenceCategoryWithMetaData` for the user photo properties, which is part of container `0x5`, "Presentity information".

```
var photoPresence = new PresenceCategoryWithMetaData(
    0x5, // The container id
    (int)PresenceRelationshipLevel.Everyone,
    new ContactCard(0x5) // Same container ID again
    {
        IsAllowedToShowPhoto = true,
        PhotoUri = "<uri to your photo here"
    });
```

You can set an `ExpiryPolicy` on this object too, should be self explainatory really. Then publish this presence object on your endpoint:

```
Endpoint.LocalOwnerPresence.BeginPublishPresence(new[] { photoPresence  }, cb => { 
    Endpoint.LocalOwnerPresence.EndPublishPresence(cb);
}, null);
```

And that should do it, really. I ended up explicitly publishing to all relationship levels because it didn't cascade the data as logically expected. This turned into quite a lengthy reply, also for my own future reference. Please let me know if this works for app endpoints too.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that you can't do this. Because it's an Application Endpoint, by definition it isn't related to any one particular user. It would certainly be nice though. :)