# Lync for Mac 2011 does not show profile pictures / avatars

Tags: image, macos, profile, lync, avatar

I'm using MS Lync for Mac version 14.0.10.
Is is not possible for me to see my or collegues avators/profile pictures.

[image]

Other Mac users in the company have the same issue. Windows users aren't affected.

I already found this issue asked by someone [on the office365 community](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/166/t/198002.aspx), but without any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your infrastructure, user photos are either stored in Active Directory (thumbnailPhoto) or in Exchange.  Lync on Windows integrates with Outlook to pull this info.

If you're a full-on O365 user, I would think you *should* see the photos.  I admit I'm not all that familiar with Office:Mac

---

Also, your photos can be stored anywhere on the inter/intranet.  Photo locations can be restricted in CsClientPolicy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set a user photo URL for one of the users (make sure it's public/web available). If this user photo does show up on Mac, it means the current photos are stored somewhere Macs cannot access them like AD (see the answer by @blaughw).

Setting user photos to a public URL also has the advantage of allowing external (federated) contacts to see your picture, as they obviously have the same problem of not being able to access your AD data.

Comment: Just found this answer and no point in me starting a new thread, as 2011 is now quite old. But I use 2011, and I cant see an option to set the URL. Where would one find this?

Comment: There is a client policy which dictates which photos can be set, see [Microsoft Lync 2010 Photo Experience](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nexthop/archive/2010/11/22/microsoft-lync-2010-photo-experience.aspx). Otherwise you can always set the photo programmatically: [Displaying a photo for an Application endpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17039196/928483).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll check them out.